# Gist (gist.el / Emacs) -- Set the `description` at the time of creation

Tags: emacs, elisp

The default behavior of `gist-region` is to leave the **description** blank.  To set the description, it is necessary to switch to the `gist-list` buffer and then use the function `gist-edit-current-description` to set the **description**.

I would like to be able to set the **description** at the same time that the gist is created, without switching to the `gist-list` buffer.  A mini-buffer prompt that defaults to the `buffer-name` would be the preferred method of handling this.  How can this be accomplished programmatically?

Here are the two main functions in `gist.el` that are responsible for the behavior described above:

```lisp
(defun gist-region (begin end &optional private callback)
  "Post the current region as a new paste at gist.github.com
Copies the URL into the kill ring.

With a prefix argument, makes a private paste."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (let* ((file (or (buffer-file-name) (buffer-name)))
         (name (file-name-nondirectory file))
         (ext (or (cdr (assoc major-mode gist-supported-modes-alist))
                  (file-name-extension file)
                  "txt"))
         (fname (concat (file-name-sans-extension name) "." ext))
         (files (list
                 (gh-gist-gist-file "file"
                                    :filename fname
                                    :content (buffer-substring begin end)))))
    (gist-internal-new files private nil callback)))

(defun gist-edit-current-description ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((id (tabulated-list-get-id))
         (gist (gist-list-db-get-gist id))
         (old-descr (oref gist :description))
         (new-descr (read-from-minibuffer "Description: " old-descr)))
    (let* ((g (clone gist
                     :files nil
                     :description new-descr))
           (api (gist-get-api t))
           (resp (gh-gist-edit api g)))
      (gh-url-add-response-callback resp
                                    (lambda (gist)
                                      (gist-list-reload))))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the function `gist-internal-new` that `gist-region` is calling.

`(gist-internal-new FILES &optional PRIVATE DESCRIPTION CALLBACK)`

The third param is the description but `gist-region` is setting it to nil. You can modify that last expression in `gist-region` to read a string from the minibuffer to specify a description

```lisp
(gist-internal-new files private (read-from-minibuffer "Gist Description: ") callback)
```

Or better yet, don't modify the function and just write your own! That way, you don't mess with other packages that use the function.

Here is just a slightly a modified version that adds an extra parameter and uses `interactive` to automatically prompt the user for a description while still allowing prefix args to make private gists.

Unlike the first example when we used `read-from-minibuffer' this one will allow you to use the function in code and specify the description directly without forcing a prompt to be used unless it's called interactively.

```lisp
;; note that we added the DESCRIPTION argument
(defun gist-region-with-description (begin end &optional description private callback)
  "Post the current region as a new paste at gist.github.com
Copies the URL into the kill ring.

With a prefix argument, makes a private paste."
  (interactive "r\nsGist Description: \nP") ;; we handle the prompt here!
  (let* ((file (or (buffer-file-name) (buffer-name)))
         (name (file-name-nondirectory file))
         (ext (or (cdr (assoc major-mode gist-supported-modes-alist))
                  (file-name-extension file)
                  "txt"))
         (fname (concat (file-name-sans-extension name) "." ext))
         (files (list
                 (gh-gist-gist-file "file"
                                    :filename fname
                                    :content (buffer-substring begin end)))))
    ;; finally we use our new arg to specify the description in the internal call
    (gist-internal-new files private description callback)))
```